# How to make onclick to fire when javascript returns false

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

The onclick doesn't work when the javascript returns false. I need javascript to return false in order to animate the button. If I return true then the onClick works but the animation doesn't work. I have tried doing __doPostBack and UseSubmitBehaviour but nothing seems to work. Any help would be really appreciated on how to fix this.

Code for asp button:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="btn_salaries" onClientClick="return fncsave();" OnClick="btn_clicked" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" type="button" class="list-group-item" Text="getCharitySalaries"/>
```

Javascript code:

```
function fncsave(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#list").click(function(){
                $("#list_of_btns").animate({left: '-290px'});
            });
        });
        return false;
    }
```

**Update:**

I'm doing the animation in ajax but I don't know if I'm doing this correctly because it does not perform the animation.

This is my code below:

```
function fncsave(){
    alert("dsfdsf");
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            $("#list_of_btns").animate({left: '-290px'});
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: try using MVC.NET and get better coupling of client/server behaviors.  By contrast, in ASPX client and server are practically two different worlds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not check for document ready event on the click event handler. Also, when someone clicks on the link you are calling fncsave function but inside that function you are subscribing to another event (click) on the tag with id list. 
If I understand correctly, you should do this:

```
function fncsave(){
        $("#list_of_btns").animate({left: '-290px'});
        return false;
    }
```

Just as a comment, "return false" means that it's not gonna continue with the normal flow of the event handling, which is submit the form.

If you return true, the form is submitted. That means the form data is sent to the server and the C# code is executed. Then, the page if fully reloaded (from scratch). In that case, the animation makes no sense and you'll need AJAX to perform an animation while the C# code is running. See this tutorial about AJAX ([Tutorial about AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)).

Comment: That makes sense, but the OnClick still doesn't work. I don't how to make this work.

Comment: OnClick is a event handler at server side and it's only executed when the JS function returns true (do post back). If you need to execute JS code and C# code, then return true instead of false. Take into account that the page will be submitted.

Comment: So do I write __doPostBack() in fncsave() or do I write this in OnClientClick()?

Comment: That's because when you do a postback (return true in JS code), the form is sent to the server, the C# code is executed and a new page is returned to the client (reloading the page from scratch). You don't want that, you want to show the animation while the C# action is running, right? in that case you need to use AJAX. That means, that your JS code will call a C# method async.

Comment: I updated my code in the question and I'm using ajax but the animation no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 function fncsave(){
        $("#list").click(function(){
             $("#list_of_btns").animate({left: '-290px'},900,function(){
                    return false;
               });
          });
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately since its still returning false it doesn't fire the OnClick event.

Comment: So you can change it to true

Comment: If I change it to true then the animation doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have a 'animated' variable with default is false. If button is clicked, check if animated is false, 'preventDefault()' cancel the submit, play animation, 'setTimeOut()' will the function after 3000ms, assign animated to true, and trigger 'click' on the button. This time, animated is true and it post data to server.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_salaries" OnClick="Button_Click" runat="server" type="button" Text="getCharitySalaries" />
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e) {

        var animated = false;
        $('#' + '<% = btn_salaries.ClientID %>').click(function (ev) {
            if (!animated) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                $(this).animate({ left: '-290px' });
                setTimeout(function () {
                    animated = true;
                    $('#' + '<% = btn_salaries.ClientID %>').trigger('click');
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
function fncsave(){
    $("#list_of_btns").animate({left: '-290px'},900,function(){
        // Do __doPostBack here
    });
    return false;
}
```

It'll delay doing the post back until after the animation is done.  An alternative would be to use update panels to avoid the flicker from the post back that'll follow the animation.